# Wifi not connecting - asks wifi password repeatedly

Tags: wireless, 16.04

wifi does not connect and repeatedly asks for wifi password, 
The LED indicator remains orange on f12/wifi key,
I dont know if wifi worked before on this computer that had windows 7 now removed.

```
Following info:
Now connected by wired connection to post this:
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 00
       serial: 14:2d:27:55:71:3f
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
       resources: irq:16 memory:b2510000-b251ffff
    lspci says
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
09:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

## Output of wireless-info script is :

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 14 Oct 2016 12:44 IST +0530

Booted last: 14 Oct 2016 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-43-lowlatency #63-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 12 14:41:17 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:2211]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName:  
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              573440  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
rt3290sta            1155072  1
sparse_keymap          16384  2 hp_wmi,intel_hid
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1486677 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

enp8s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp8s0' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.3  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eac:abef:1ce3:c21f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1008 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:403483 (403.4 KB)  TX bytes:136529 (136.5 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

eno1      Ralink STA  ESSID:""  Nickname:"RT3290STA"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.432 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'Methodlabs' [AC2]>   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:-57 dBm  Noise level:-57 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp8s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp8s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp8s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain.name

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1284     1  0 12:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp8s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp8s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:08:00.0/net/enp8s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp8s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       e6e17da3-ba4c-3762-ae7a-a1171b47ae0c
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   e6e17da3-ba4c-3762-ae7a-a1171b47ae0c | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.3/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             203.153.44.44
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          domain.name
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1476436061
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.3
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = domain.name
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 203.153.44.44 8.8.8.8
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::eac:abef:1ce3:c21f/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::1e5f:2bff:feda:5712
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::1e5f:2bff:feda:5712/128, nh = ::, mt = 100

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe (Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2860
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:09:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1,0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   71ce7f1f-87e3-43fc-b8fa-7a383eb24a9f | Methodlabs
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[2]:   0bdee8f7-cd13-4ed6-940c-95c4dec57f66 | Methodlabs 1

SSID            BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
Methodlabs      <MAC 'Methodlabs' [AC2]>  Infra  5     2432 MHz  54 Mbit/s  92      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  no        
D-Link_DIR-816  <MAC 'D-Link_DIR-816' [AC1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  44 Mbit/s  30      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Methodlabs]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Methodlabs | type=wifi | permissions=user:piyush:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'eno1' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Methodlabs
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Methodlabs 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Methodlabs 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:piyush:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'eno1' [IF1]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Methodlabs
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp8s0    no frequency information.

eno1      11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp8s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)

eno1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'D-Link_DIR-816' [AC1]>
                    Protocol:802.11b/g/n
                    ESSID:"D-Link_DIR-816"
                    Mode:Managed
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=10/100  Signal level=-86 dBm  Noise level=-81 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Methodlabs' [AC2]>
                    Protocol:802.11b/g/n
                    ESSID:"Methodlabs"
                    Mode:Managed
                    Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                    Quality=100/100  Signal level=-39 dBm  Noise level=-92 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:54 Mb/s
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-43-lowlatency/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-43-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[rt3290sta]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-43-lowlatency/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt3290sta.ko
version:        2.6.0.0_rev1
srcversion:     96CD86FDB670E3BFC172F9B
depends:        
vermagic:       4.4.0-43-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           mac:rt28xx: wireless mac addr (charp)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ralink.conf]
blacklist rt2800pci
blacklist rt2x00pci  

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/osspd.conf]
blacklist snd-pcm-oss
blacklist snd-mixer-oss
blacklist snd-seq-oss

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  125.427950] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: link up
[  125.427961] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp8s0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Repromt of password box displays when password is wrong..ensure it type again..else it will be some different problem

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and *certainly not TKIP*. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.